# How is AFCI Powered?

Tags: circuit-breaker

With arc-fault circuit interrupters once there is overcurrent or arcs what is powering the electronics inside the AFCI that are doing the signal analysis? Won't the electronics get damaged if it's being powered by the problematic circuit?

Answer (score 0):

The overcurrent detection part of an AFCI is like a regular breaker so it trips magnetically due to instant gross overload or thermally due to long-term minor overload.

But after the regular breaker, there is a power supply to provide stable low voltage supply for e.g. current measurement and the chip that is determining if the current consumption profile matches an arc fault or not.

So without going into any details, the power supply could be just designed to have enough capacitance for energy storage, to provide stable voltage for long enough time as needed for the arc fault sensing circuits to do their function properly.

Basically it's no different from an appliance that stays powered say half a second after you have unplugged the mains cord.